# Jquery: how to know whether value is updated live?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have `span` that can become `input` on click to make live update. On `blur` on the input I want to check the value is the same as previous value (because I want to update only if value is changed). How can I achieve this in jquery with this code?

```
$("ul.pagination-list").on 'click', 'span[editable=text]', ->
    input = $("<input />",
        type: "text"
        name: "editarea"
        id: $(this).parent().attr("id")
        value: $(this).html()
    )

    $(this).replaceWith input

$("ul.pagination-list").on 'blur', 'input[name=editarea]', -> 

    ### here i want to check whether value is changed ###

    span = $("<span />",
        class: 'span3'
        editable: 'text'
    ).text($(this).val())

    $(this).replaceWith(span)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the *attribute* `value` contains the initial value, while the *property* `value` (which is read by the `val()` function) contains the current value. You can use `$(this).attr('value')` to read the initial value.

Example:

```
var input = $('<input>', { value: 'asdf' });

$(document.body).append(input);
input.focus();

$(document.body).on('blur', 'input', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DSdwL/

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the global variables and then check if there are any changes. This might not be the best solution but it will work.

First create a new global variable with default value of `""`
`var temp = "";`

Then on `blur` method, when it is called add this:

`if(temp !== $(this).val()){`
`//Do something`
`}else{`
`//Do something` 
`}`

Also, don't forget to assign a new value to `temp` after this 
`temp = $(this).val()`

Comment: cannot use global, it is in a form of list, there might be 2 or 3 or 4 or more rows edited at one time